# Difference between System.setProperty and Security.setProperty

Tags: java, sockets, security, ssl, sslsocketfactory

Found below line of code in a java application designed to run on a custom chip.

```
System.setProperty("ssl.SocketFactory.provider", "some.custom.socketFactory");
```

I infer from the internet that "ssl.SocketFactory.provider" is a property to be set on java.security.Security class.

I am confused if setting "ssl.SocketFactory.provider" as System property instead of Security property makes any difference(positive or negative) and is it right, I mean are System and Security sub sets or super sets of each other, so it  does not matter on whom the "ssl.SocketFactory.provider" property is set.

P.S: 
1) The java application on chip successfully managed to communicate with server with Server authentication, but when Client authentication is requested from updated server, the SSlSocketFactory(created from SSLContext initialized with verified Trust and Key Manager factories) is unable to create a socket at servers IP and port.The thread blocks forever at .createSocket(IP,port);

2) I did lot of searching on the internet, but unable to connect the dots between these classes and if I am missing or doing something wrong.

Comment: The docs do seem to say to use security property.  `The first time this method is called, the security property "ssl.SocketFactory.provider" is examined.`  So you might be right.  Hard to be sure when dealing with custom hardware though.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/net/ssl/SSLSocketFactory.html#getDefault--

Answer (score 5):

The `Security.getProperty` and `setProperty` methods are setting properties in a `Properties` object that is private to the `Security` class.

> I mean are System and Security subsets or supersets of each other.

No.

> so it does not matter on whom the `"ssl.SocketFactory.provider"` property is set.

It does matter.

---

The default security properties are loaded from a file in the Java installation; i.e. `"$JAVA_HOME/lib/security/java.security"` where `$JAVA_HOME` denotes the *effective* java home.  These can be overridden via a properties file that is specified via the `"java.security.properties"` property in the `System` properties.

So setting `"ssl.SocketFactory.provider"` in the system properties *will not work*.  However, if you:

1. create a security properties override file,
2. put the `"ssl.SocketFactory.provider"` property into it, and
3. add an appropriate `"java.security.properties"` refering to the override file to your `System` properties; e.g. using a `-D` commandline option.

then that *should* work.

---

(The above details are gleaned from reading the Java 8 source code.  The implementation might be different in other versions.)